# Sequence Word Problems Confusion

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have questions dealing with the placement of $a_0$ and $a_1$ in sequence-based word problems.

For example, I have two: A certain culture initially contains 10,000 bacteria and increases by 20% every hour. 
(a) Find a formula for the number N(t) of bacteria present after t hours.

Here, 10,000 would be taken on by $a_0$, so the formula would be $N(t)=10000∗(1.2)^{10}$.

How can I distinguish between these in a word problem? Is $10,000=a_0$ because nothing about it has changed, so nothing has been 'done' to it yet? But $a_1$ is the "starting value" in a sequence, so why isn't 10000=$a_1$?

Second question: A certain drug has a half life of 2 hours in the bloodstream. The drug is formulated to be administered in doses of D milligrams every 4 hours, but D is yet to be determined. 
Find a formula to get the milligrams of drug in the bloodstream after the nth dose. Show that this sum is $\frac43D$.

D is our starting value, or $a_0$. However I'm wrong since the answer is $a_n=D∗\frac14(n−1)$, so clearly D is $a_1$. Why is this so?

Please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining the terms as $a_t$ where $t$ is time, then $a_0=N(0)$ will be the bacteria count at $t=0$ which is, as you said, is 10,000 (for the first problem).

However for the second problem it asks for a formula for the mg at the $n$th dose, so you define $a_n$ as the mg at the $n$th dose. In this case $a_0$=0 because at 0 doses there are 0 mg. But at $a_1$ we have D mg. As for an $a_n$ expression, we can see that $$a_n=D+{D \over 4}+{D \over 16}+...+{D\over 4^{n-1}}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {D \over 4^i}= \frac43D$$

Comment: I see, that makes everything much clearer! I had completely overlooked the fact. Thanks.